# Strange equality issue with Javascript object properties

Tags: javascript, object

Why after executing that snippet of code:

```
var a = {};
var b = {};

var g = {};
g[a] = "aa";
g[b] = "dd";
```

the value of g[a] is "dd"?

a == b is false so what is going on here?

Comment: JavaScript implementations might have some bizarre-hidden-ones. Which Browser / JavaScript engine are you testing with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript object **keys can only be strings**. When you store `g[a] = 'aa'`, a is converted to a string using the `toString()` method,<sup>1</sup> so you're actually storing `'aa'` at `g[a.toString()]`.

In this case, `a.toString()` is `'[object Object]'`, which is equal to `b.toString()`.

To make it really obvious, the code in your question is equivalent to this:

```
var g = {};
g['[object Object]'] = 'aa';
g['[object Object]'] = 'dd';
```

Moral of the story: just don't try to use anything other than strings as property names.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Source: [MDC: JavaScript Member Operators - Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Property_names)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `b` are objects, and you'd be using them as keys in doing `g[a]` or `g[b]`, which can't work since associative arrays can only use valid variable names or strings as keys.

What are you trying to accomplish?

```
var a = "a";
var b = "b";

var g = {};
g[a] = "aa";
g[b] = "dd";
```

Would work properly, however.