# How to load hash in a loop using objects as keys in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I get unexpected behavior when trying to load a hash using objects as keys; ie, when retrieving my data later the hash always refers to the last key used.  I would expect this to be due to the behavior of closures, however, I thought that I have done what would be necessary to prevent this:

```
var hash = {};
var arry = [];
var list = [{val:"a"},{val:"b"},{val:"c"}];

var len  = list.length;

dump("load : \n");

for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {

  let pos = i;
  let obj = list[pos];
  hash[obj] = obj.val;
  arry.push(obj);
  dump("    "+obj.val+"    "+hash[obj]+"\n");
}

dump("retrieve : \n");

for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {

  let pos = i;
  let obj = list[pos];
  dump("    "+obj.val+"    "+arry[pos].val+"    "+hash[obj]+"\n");
}
```

output is:

```
load :
    a    a
    b    b
    c    c
retrieve :
    a    a    c
    b    b    c
    c    c    c
```

I have purposely gone overboard in trying to prevent this by raising the scope of the iteration objects using let, still I am apparently missing something.  I would like to understand the reason behind this, and how to prevent it using Javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Object keys in JavaScript can only be strings.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Property_names) This means that if you pass something that is not a string, it gets converted to a string. Since you're using objects that don't "override" [`Object.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString), they'll all have the same string representation (it's `"[object Object]"`), which is why the hash always refers to the last key used.

More here: [Strange equality issue with Javascript object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5771442/139010)

Answer (score 0):

To extend [@Matt Ball answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17253776/887539):

You can use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to string objects.

```
var a = {};
a.b = 1;

JSON.stringify(a);
// '{"b": 1}'
```

Note: You can't stringify circular objects:

```
var a = {};
a.a = a;

JSON.stringify(a);
// TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```